# Make a dynamic contact chatlist with sorting and paging using mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I need to build a chat using nodejs and mongodb. In this chat I need to mount the contact list by ordering the latest posts and applying paging 15 items per page. I wonder how I can do this dynamically using mongodb / mongoose.

For example, on the first page I seek contacts ordered by those who sent messages last. If loading the second page, and any new message has arrived, the order of chatlist have probably changed.

How I can ride my query and do this treatment?

My User Schema is:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true},
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true, select: false},
    created_at: {type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now}
});
```

My Message Schema is:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    content: {type: String, required: true},
    type: {type: String, required: true, default: 'text'},
    status: {type: String, default: 'not_read'},
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    read_at: {type: Date},
    userFrom: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    userTo: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true}
});
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1:

```
var itensPerPage = 15;
var skip = page !== undefined ? page * itensPerPage : 0;
pages = Math.ceil(pages / itensPerPage);

Message
.aggregate([
    { '$sort': { 
        'created_at': -1 
    }},
    { "$skip": skip },
    { "$limit": itensPerPage },
    { '$match': { 
        $or: [
            { userFrom: psychologist.id_user }, 
            { userTo: psychologist.id_user }
        ] 
    }},
    { '$group': { 
            '_id': {
                'userFrom': '$userFrom', 
                'userTo': '$userTo'
            },
        }
    },
])
.exec(function (err, id_users) {
    if(err){
        callback(new Error("Something went wrong while trying to agregate the psychologist users."), null);
    }else{
        var users_from_id_map = id_users.map(function(x) { return x._id.userFrom} );
        var users_to_id_map = id_users.map(function(x) { return x._id.userTo} );

        var chatlist = [];
        var received = users_from_id_map.length;

        for(var i = 0; i < users_from_id_map.length; i++){
            Message
            .findOne({$or : [{userFrom: users_from_id_map[i], userTo: users_to_id_map[i]}]})
            .sort('-created_at')
            .exec(function (err, message) {
                if(err){
                    callback(new Error("Something went wrong while trying to find last message."), null);
                }else{

                    if(message){

                        var user_chat_id;
                        if(psychologist.id_user.equals(message.userFrom)){
                            user_chat_id = message.userTo;
                        }else{
                            user_chat_id = message.userFrom;
                        }

                        var is_mine = false;
                        if(message.userFrom.equals(psychologist.id_user)){
                            is_mine = true;
                        }

                        chatlist.push({
                            id_user: user_chat_id,
                            lastMessage: {
                                content: (message.content.length > 35 ? message.content.substring(0,35)+"..." : message.content), 
                                date: message.created_at,
                                is_mine: is_mine
                            }
                        });

                    }else{
                        chatlist.push({
                            id_user: user_chat_id,
                            lastMessage: null
                        });
                    }

                    received--;
                    if(received == 0){
                        next(err, psychologist, chatlist, pages);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Paging can be implemented in various ways in MongoDB.

You could use `limit` and `offset` although this will become slow when requesting higher pages.

Another way is to use `greaterThan` with the last contact you have seen together with `limit` to, say, get the next 15 contacts.

Inconsistencies (if new messages are send during paging) cannot easily be prevented.

That said, MongoDB may not be a good choice for a live chat because it has no support for streaming queries.

Comment: Could you give me an example for this case?
I will update the post description with my start point.
Thanks